# PHP script is not exceuted by laravel cron

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx, cron

I have php script ran by cron. When I manually run

```
php /var/www/html/ngix/hotshoponline.com/api/artisan schedule:run
```

it works fine, the script takes about 2 mins, and I can get the output I need.

But when it's called by cron like this

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/ngix/hotshoponline.com/api/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

it is not working 
i tried with -f and  tried with /usr/bin/php nothing is working

Comment: Have you checked `/var/log/cron` to see if there's a hint there? You may need to take out the redirect to `/dev/null`

Answer (score 3):

In order to see the possible errors, add an output file.

Something like this

`* * * * * php /var/www/html/ngix/hotshoponline.com/api/artisan schedule:run > /var/log/error.log 2>&1`

Then tail the error.log file to see if there are errors.

```
tail -f /var/log/error.log
```

Comment: i typed in terminal  tail -f syslog then i see this error ( Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).

Comment: Check the date and time since you encountered this error and compare when you configured the script in the cron. If you have it since before it means this is not related to your issue. Also, is there any error in your output file in the cron?

Comment: no error nothing on output file it says Running scheduled command: job_ExternalProduct artisan command out printing no error at all